# How to see the commands issued by Eclipse for my Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Luna. I created a simple Java project named "JP_Test" with only 1 class:

```
package com.srh.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class UserModel implements Serializable {
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

I am showing the `Console` view (using *Window* --> *Show View*).

Then I build the project (using *Project* --> *Build Project*). I was hoping to see Eclipse issuing `javac` command in the `Console` view. But nothing shows up.

How can I see the commands issued by Eclipse for my Java project in this case?

Comment: why do I get a negative vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't use `javac` to compile, it uses its own compiler and there are no commands to show.

Why would you want to see them anyway?

Comment: I wanted to see if eclipse also does it the same way as we do it usually at the command prompt. So what is the purpose of `Console` view?

Comment: @srh It's where the text goes when you do `System.out.println("Hello, world!");`. It has to go somewhere when running in an IDE after all.

Comment: aha. So its for program output. Makes sense.